# AS3 Accessing elements in an array once only

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array like so...

var pointsArray:Array = [100, 200, 250, 1000, 1500];

a for loop ...

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<27; i+=1) 
{
ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].text = "Locked";
ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].textColor = 0x666699; 
}
```

and an achievements function ...

```
if (TotalScore >= pointscollectedArray[0])
{
    ach.scrollp.content.ach0.text = "Unlocked";
    ach.scrollp.content.ach0.textColor = 0xFF9900;
}
```

etc etc

No issues at all with the data displaying in an achievements interface. But what I am trying to do is display a movie clip during the actual game that tells the player when they have unlocked an achievement. The problem is I don't know how to display the movieclip once only per unlocked achievement ie the movieclip doesn't display again until the next achievement is unlocked. 
I have no idea how to access the elements in an array only once.

I'm a noob at AS3 so I hope I've explained everything properly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you redesigned your achievement architecture. But for a simple fix, something like this:

```
if (TotalScore >= pointscollectedArray[0] && 
    ach.scrollp.content.ach0.text != "Unlocked")
{
  ach.scrollp.content.ach0.text = "Unlocked";
  ach.scrollp.content.ach0.textColor = 0xFF9900;
  // play movie
}
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. But it displays the movie clip whether an achievement is unlocked or not.

Comment: My achievement system works fine. Go to the achievement interface after a round of the game is finished and it displays all correctly. What I am trying to do is play an additional movie clip when the game (a quiz) is actually going. So when an achievement is unlocked mid-play it displays a movie clip letting the player know. BUT the movie clip should only play once per achievement. So if a player scores 100 points and that is the first achievement then the movie clip plays. Until they get to the next level (200 points) it shouldn't play.

Comment: I thought it would have something to do with splicing the array. Say once the first value in the array is read the movie clip fires then that value is removed and so forth until there are no values left in the array.

Comment: I took onboard redesigning the achievements and thx to those for their input.

Comment: var i:int;
        var j:int;

     OuterLoop:   for (i= 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    { 
 {
  showAchPopUp(true);
 }
 
                for (j= i+1; j < points.length{
     
      if (TotalScore >= points[i])
 {
  ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].text = "Unlocked";
  ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].textColor = 0x9900cc;
  
 }
     
            if (points[i] === points[j]) {
                      
      showAchPopUp(false);
                        break OuterLoop;

                        }
      
  }
 }
 }

Answer (score 0):

It is better to redesign your code. I can suggest you something like this:

```
var iLevel: int = 0; // This is the achievement that is reached. Player starts from 0 but if your game support save, iLevel can be different;
var nTotalLevels: int = 27; // This is total amount of achievements you have

for ( var i:int = 0; i < iLevel; ++i )
{
    //This code show unlocked achievements
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].text = "Unlocked";
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+i].textColor = 0xFF9900;
}
for ( var k:int = iLevel; k < nTotalLevels; ++k )
{
    // This code show locked achievements;
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+k].text = "Locked";
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+k].textColor = 0x666699; 
}
```

so in this case when the player receive new achievement, you can show it like this

```
if ( TotalScore >= pointscollectedArray[0] )
{
    ++iLevel;
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+iLevel].text = "Unlocked";
    ach.scrollp.content["ach"+iLevel].textColor = 0xFF9900;
    // play movie
}
```

I hope that I understand right what you need;

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I probably didn't explain it well enough. Yes there are 26 fields that need to display locked until otherwise. But those levels are not all points collected. There are other 5 other achievements such as played, correct so that's why I have my code the way it is. I think that your code would work if it was just all the one variable. Also the game does save the achievements.